# Angular TrngGrid extra columns getting added

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using trnggrid with angular to display my data in grid format. The following is my code

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <table tr-ng-grid="" items="products" page-items="5" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field-name="Id" display-name="Id" enable-filtering="true" enable-sorting="true" cell-width="10em" display-align="right">
                </th>
                <th field-name="Name" display-name="Name" enable-filtering="true" enable-sorting="true" cell-width="10em" display-align="right">
                </th>
                <th field-name="Unit" display-name="Unit" enable-filtering="true" enable-sorting="true" cell-width="10em" display-align="right">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product in products">

                <td>{{product.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.Unit}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a ng-click="viewProduct(gridDisplayItem.Id)">View |</a>&nbsp;
                    <a ng-click="editProduct(gridDisplayItem.Id)"> Edit |</a>&nbsp;
                    <a ng-click="deleteProduct(gridDisplayItem.Id)">Delete</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

However when I run this, three extra columns are getting added with invalid header.Have put the screenshot in this link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i9EB.png

Can someone suggest what a solution for this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ng-repeat directive in the tbody and remove the first 3 they are not needed since the the table directive has already handled that for you....

View | 
                     Edit | 
                    Delete